How to subtract Personal from Total watch hours under Analytics to get Public watch hours for comparison to the annual figure under Monetization?
There are two places to look up Watch Hours in YouTube Studio: under Analytics and under Monetization.

Under Analytics, the aggregate of personal and private watch hours is listed, whereas
Under Monetization, only public watch hours are listed.

Monetization depends only on Public watch hours, whereas the aggregate of Public and Personal watch hours has no practical use to the YouTube creator. This obfuscation is suspect on the part of YouTube.
How can I subtract Personal watch hours over the past 28 days under Analytics to get Public watch hours for comparison to the annual figure under Monetization?

Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please [edit] your question so it includes a practical problem to be solved.  See help > dont-ask and [ask]
